# PostgreSQL: WITH SELECT and random()

Tags: postgresql

I ran into a postgre behavior that is incomprehensible to me, maybe someone can explain to me what's wrong?

test table:

```
create table "test" (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR
);

insert into test("id", "name") values
(250, 'Test 1'),
(5, 'Test 2'),
(50, 'Test 3'),
(55, 'Test 4'),
(2365, 'Test 5'),
(1, 'Test 6'),
(2, 'Test 7'),
(88, 'Test 8');
```

the query:

```
WITH numered_test as (
  select
    "id",
    row_number() over (order by "id") num
  from
    test
)
select * from numered_test where num = FLOOR(random() * 8 + 1);
```

the trick is that the query can return zero or *multiple* rows. why?

tasted with 10.21 and 0.13.-2.tomorrow beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the query can return zero or multiple rows is that `FLOOR(random() * 8 + 1)` is evaluated more than once and returns different results.
This query evaluates it only once within the materialized `random_val`  CTE and behaves as expected.

```sql
WITH numered_test as (
  select id, row_number() over (order by id) num from test
),
random_val as materialized (
  select FLOOR(random() * 8 + 1) r
)
select nt.* from numered_test nt, random_val where num = r;
```